# Executar um som em outra tela quando é inserido um registro novo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Bom dia a todos!

Bom! gostaria de uma grande ajuda de vocês. Estou tentando fazer um **Painel de chamada de pacientes** bem simples para quando o médico esteja no consultório veja uma tabela de pacientes e clique o nome desejado e na sala de recepção apareça o nome dele e toque um som.
No momento só consigo fazer que toque um som no PC que é chamado que seria o do médico, pois não seria o ideal já que teria que colocar caixas de sons do lado externo para cada consultório.

Esse é meu código:

```html
**db.php**

<?php

  $servidor = "localhost";
  $usuario= "root";
  $password = "";
  $db = "painel";

  $conexao = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $password, $db);

?>

**chamar.php** 

<?php
  include "db.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>CHAMAR CLIENTE</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
</head>
<body>

 <div id="conteudo">

  <form method="POST" action="chamar.php">
   <input type="text" name="nome">   
   <input id="id2" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Chamar Paciente" 
            onclick="ajax();">

  </form>

  <?php
   if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO chamar (nome) VALUES ('$nome')";

    $executar = $conexao->query($consulta);

    if ($executar) {
     //EXECUTA O SOM QUANDO É INSERIDO UM REGISTRO
     echo "<embed loop='false' src='beep.mp3' hidden='true' 
                    autoplay='true'>";
    }

   }
  ?>

 </div>

</body>
</html>


**index.php**

<?php
include "db.php";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>PAINEL DE CHAMADA</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function ajax(){
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

   req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById('chamar').innerHTML = req.responseText;     
    }
   }
     
   req.open('GET', 'painel.php', true);
   req.send();
  }

  setInterval(function(){ajax();}, 3000);
 </script>

</head>
<body>

 <div id="conteudo">
  <div id="div-chamar">
   <div id="chamar"></div>
  </div>

  <?php

   $consulta = "SELECT * FROM chamar";

     $executar = $conexao->query($consulta);

     if ($executar) {
      //SÓ EXECUTA O SOM QUANDO É ATUALIZA A PÁGINA
      echo "<embed loop='false' src='beep.mp3' hidden='true' 
                        autoplay='true'>";
     }

  ?>

 </div>

</body>
</html>


**painel.php**

<?php
 include "db.php";
 
 $consulta = "SELECT * FROM chamar ORDER BY id DESC";
 $executar = $conexao->query($consulta); 
 $chamar = $executar->fetch_array();


?>
<h1 id="prova" class="mudar" style="color: #1C62C4; font-size: 80px;"><?php echo $chamar['nome']; ?></h1>

Agradeço desde já!!!
```

Comment: pode enviar a estrutura do banco pra eu pode replicar aqui e fazer um teste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente você precisará de uma página que fica consultando a tabela **chamar**

modifiquei então a **painel.php** para capturar os dados necessários e devolve-los em JSON:

```
<?php
    include "db.php";

    //ARMAZENA O TOTAL
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM chamar ";
    $executar = $conexao->query($consulta); 
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($executar);

    //SELECIONA APENAS OS 6 ULTIMOS
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM chamar ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
    $exec = $conexao->query($sql); 
    $ultimos = array();
    $i = 0;

    while($chamar = $exec->fetch_array()){
        //eis o proximo
        if($i==0){
            $proximo = $chamar['nome'];
        }else{

            // forma os 5 ultimos
            array_push($ultimos,
                array('nome' => $chamar['nome'])
            ); 
            //para pegar mais que 5, aumente o limit no $sql;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    echo json_encode(
        [
            'total' => $total, //quantos nomes foram chamados
            'proximo' => $proximo, // nome do proximo
            'ultimos' => $ultimos // array contendo o nome dos 5 ultimos
        ]
    );

?>
```

criei daí uma pagina chamada **painel_exibe.php** que irá usar a painel.php para exibir os dados:

```
<style>
#painel{
    font-family:"Arial";
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 16px;
}

#painel h1{
    font-size: 24px;        
}

#painel h2{
    font-size: 18px;
}
</style>

<div id="painel">

<!-- conta quantos foram chamados, inicializa com 0 -->
<input type="hidden" id="total" value="0"> 

<!-- exibe o nome do proximo -->
<h2>Próximo:</h2>
<h1 id="proximo">Carregando...</h1> 

<hr>
<!-- exibe o nome dos 5 ultimos -->
<h2>Ultimos chamados:</h2>
<div id="ultimos">Carregando...</div> 

<div id="som"></div>

</div>

<!-- jquery -->
<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    setInterval(function(){
        total = $("#total").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'painel.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json', //espera o retorno em jSon
            success: function(json){
                //Só chama o proximo se a contagem de pacientes que chegou é maior 
                //que a ultima registrada
                if(total < json.total){
                    //NOME DO ULTIMO
                    $("#proximo").html(json.proximo);

                    $("#proximo").fadeOut(); //efeito para piscar
                    $("#proximo").fadeIn(); //efeito para piscar

                    //ARMAZENA A ULTIMA CONTAGEM
                    $("#total").val(json.total);

                    // escreve os ultimos
                    var nome_ultimos ='';
                    for(i=0; i< json.ultimos.length; i++){
                        nome_ultimos += json.ultimos[i].nome + '<br>';
                    }                    
                    $("#ultimos").html(nome_ultimos);

                    $("#ultimos").fadeOut(); //efeito para piscar
                    $("#ultimos").fadeIn(); //efeito para piscar

                    //REFAZ O HTML DO SOM PRA TOCAR O BEEP
                    $("#som").html("<embed loop='false' src='beep.mp3' hidden='true'  autoplay='true'>");

                }
            }
        });       
    }, 15* 1000); //EXECUTA A CADA 15 SEGUNDOS
  </script>
```

**Explicando esse código passo a passo:**

1 - Este campo serve para armazenar o ultimo n° de registros de nomes que chegaram a partir do banco de dados. Não é interessante ler o nome e comparar com o ultimo pois é comum que pessoas possuam exatamente o mesmo nome (Por exemplo João Silva).

```
<!-- conta quantos foram chamados, inicializa com 0 -->
<input type="hidden" id="total" value="0">
```

2 - Lugar onde vamos colocar o nome do ultimo cliente chamado:

```
<!-- exibe o nome do proximo -->
<h2>Próximo:</h2>
<h1 id="proximo">Carregando...</h1>
```

3 - Exibe o nome dos 5 ultimos chamados (Para as pessoas saberem se perderam ou não a vez)

```
<hr>
<!-- exibe o nome dos 5 ultimos -->
<h2>Ultimos chamados:</h2>
<div id="ultimos">Carregando...</div>
```

4 - div que vamos usar só pra recolocar o código que toca o som:

```
<div id="som"></div>
```

5 - JQUERY para usarmos o ajax:

```
<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

6 - Requisição AJAX para **painel.php** - Nessa página iremos :

a) contar quantos pacientes temos, para adicionar no campo "total"
b) guardar o nome do proximo paciente
c) guardar um array com o nome dos ultimos pacientes chamados

(veja o **codigo da painel.php** dela no inicio da resposta)

Explicações nos comentários do código:

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
    total = $("#total").val(); //armazena o ultimo total registrado
    $.ajax({
        url: 'painel.php', //url para a qual faremos a requisição e obteremos os dados
        type: 'GET', //metodo GET
        dataType: 'json', //Forma na qual teremos as respostas (JSON)
        success: function(json){ //armazena a resposta na variavel "json"
            //Só chama o próximo se a contagem de pacientes que chegou é maior 
            //que a ultima registrada
            if(total < json.total){

                //NOME DO ULTIMO
                $("#proximo").html(json.proximo);

                $("#proximo").fadeOut(); //efeito para piscar
                $("#proximo").fadeIn(); //efeito para piscar

                //ARMAZENA A ULTIMA CONTAGEM
                $("#total").val(json.total);

                // escreve os ultimos

                var nome_ultimos =''; //inicializa a var

                for(i=0; i< json.ultimos.length; i++){
                    nome_ultimos += json.ultimos[i].nome + '<br>'; // vai concatenando os nomes
                }                    
                $("#ultimos").html(nome_ultimos);

                $("#ultimos").fadeOut(); //efeito para piscar
                $("#ultimos").fadeIn(); //efeito para piscar

                //REFAZ O HTML DO SOM PRA TOCAR O BEEP
                $("#som").html("<embed loop='false' src='beep.mp3' hidden='true'  autoplay='true'>");

            }
        }
    });       
}, 15* 1000); //EXECUTA A CADA 15 SEGUNDOS
</script>
```

Comment: na tela que vai ficar visivel pro pessoal da recepção, você carrega a pagina painel_exibe.php e deixa aberta...

Comment: Will Knippelberg! Era tudo que eu precisava. Codificação perfeito... Valeu mestre!!!

Comment: Vota como resposta útil então pra dar aquela moral :D